# How to copy all HTML files from a directory tree to a single directory

Tags: osx, find, wildcards, cp

I want to copy all the `.html` files from `myDir` and its subdirectories to `~/otherDir`. Here's what I tried, but it doesn't work:

```
$ find myDir -name *.html -print | xargs -0 cp ~/otherDir
usage: cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvX] source_file target_file
       cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvX] source_file ... target_directory
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`find myDir -name '*.html' -print0 | xargs -0 -J % cp % ~/otherdir`

Comment: -J is not in gnu xargs (4.4.2)

Comment: @simpatico: It's a BSD extension, allowing passing multiple elements even when there are subsequent arguments. There's no GNU equivalent AFAIK.

Answer (score 12):

First of all, the shell is globbing the '*' for you. Either escape it with `\` or use quotes around `*.html`

Like so:

`find myDir -name "*.html"` or `find myDir -name \*.html`

Skip the use of `xargs` with `find`'s `-exec` switch:

`find myDir -name "*.html" -exec cp {} ~/otherDir \;`

This works because `{}` takes the place of the file that `find` found, and is executed once for each match.

Also note that this will flatten the copy of the source directory. Example:

```
myDir/a.html
myDir/b/c.html
```

will yield

```
otherdir/a.html
otherdir/c.html
```

Comment: on the mac I don't have -t but $ find MR -name "*.html" -exec cp ~/debug {} \; prints: "cp: /Users/simpatico/debug is a directory (not copied)." for each html file

Comment: Oh, you didn't mention that in your question. It would probably be helpful to others if you could tag your question with "osx". You can still do this with -exec - I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Worse, it will also copy both `mydir/a/a.html` and `mydir/b/a.html` to `otherdir/a.html` and it's not entirely obviously predictable which one winds up copied over last, which is *probably* not something you want...

Comment: @simpatico, you got the order wrong. It's `-exec cp {} ~/debug/ \;` not `-exec cp ~/debug {} \;` for what should be fairly obvious reasons once you think about it...

Answer (score 4):

So you want to copy all the `.html` files in some source directory and its subdirectories, all to a single directory (i.e. collapsing the hierarchy)?

[POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html) Standard:

```
find myDir -name '*.html' -type f -exec sh -c 'cp "$@" "$0"' ~/otherDir {} +
```

Note that `~/otherDir` becomes parameter 0 to the intermediate shell, which allows for the source files to be precisely `"$@"`. Leaving the target directory outside the shell has the additional advantage that you won't run into quoting issues if that's a variable in the parent shell script (`-exec sh -c 'cp "$@" "$0"' "$target"`).

For older systems that don't have `find … -exec … +`:

```
find myDir -name '*.html' -type f -exec cp {} ~/otherDir \;
```

I your shell is bash ≥4 or zsh:

```
shopt -s globstar  # only for bash, put it in your `.bashrc`
cp myDir/**/*.html ~/otherDir/
```

Comment: setopt globstar doesn't work on bash 4.2 both on mac and linux.

Comment: @simpatico: Sorry, that's `shopt -s` (`setopt` is the corresponding command in zsh).

Comment: Isn't `-type f` evaluated after `-name "*.html"`? While a.html is a valid directory name, I wouldn't expect one. Maybe `-type f` would make more sense before checking the file name, but I guess there is rarely a difference in the execution speed.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
find myDir -name '*.html' -exec cp -t ~/otherdir {} +
```

One problem with this approach is that it doesn't create any subdirectories so all files get put in `~/otherDir`  and files that are named the same but in different parts of the `myDir` tree don't get copied.

If this would cause you a problem then you can use the following to create the same directory tree within the `~/otherDir` tree

```
find myDir -name '*.html' | cpio -pdm ~/otherdir
```

I don't have a mac

```
find myDir -name '*.html' -print | xargs -I {} cp  {} ~/otherDir
```

or if you can

```
find myDir -name '*.html' -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} cp  {} ~/otherDir
```

as this will be safe for files with spaces in the name.

Comment: @lain - did you notice my mac limited cp w/o -t? I actually intend not to copy the structure, so cmd would be ideal if it worked, but writing the cmd w/o -t doesn't do the trick (I still get the usage printed).

Comment: There is no "-t" switch on "cp" command in Mavericks (at least), so it is GNU/Linux solution.

Comment: @DenisBarmenkov I believe I addressed that about half way down my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Does OSX support -execdir for find?

```
 find ./myDir -name "*.html" -execdir cp {} /abspath/to/otherDir ";"
```

Gnu/find suggests using -execdir instead of -exec for most cases.

Comment: [It does](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/find.1.html). So do all (recent enough) BSDs. `-execdir` is better in case a directory is moved while `find` is operating, but it's unfortunately not portable.

Answer (score 0):

```
ls myDir/*.html | xargs -I {} cp {} ~/otherDir
```

Comment: This is just a trivial variation on the answers that have already been given, with a few drawbacks.  For example, it finds only files in the top-level ``myDir``, and the question asks for files from ``myDir`` *and its subdirectories.*