# Is there a BASH command for copying all files from a directory tree and putting all the files in a single directory?

Tags: linux, bash, cp

I have a ton of notes categorized into folders, but I think it might be better to put them all into one folder instead. Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to copy all html files from a directory to another?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12966/how-to-copy-all-html-files-from-a-directory-to-another)

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -type f -execdir mv {} /my/dest/path/ \;
```

***Warning*** if you have file name clashes this will lose some of the files with repeated names.

Comment: if you don't have execdir on your find you can always use exec instead.

Comment: @Paul R - yes, I forgot that there, it's added now.

Comment: depending on `mv` implementation, `-i` option may be of use to protect from collisions.

Comment: @Michael -b or -n might also be relevant for handling collisions, depending on which mv it is and what the desired behaviour is.

Comment: I would use cp first, and remove the original only after verifying that everything is fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ set globstar
$ cp /source/dir/**/* /destination/dir/
```

The first line enables the recursive `**` globbing in Bash (not necessary in Zsh).