# rsync - moving every JPG/jpg file from one hard drive to a single directory with a shell script

Tags: rsync

I am looking for some direction - cause it sort of works, but doesn't.

I have a local hard drive and would like to copy ALL .JPG and .jpg files to a **single** directory on another local hard drive.

using rsync - my thinking: (source hard drive is a windows machine - file names have spaces)
-- get a list of all directory's on the source hard drive and put into a text file
-- edit dir list text file to add quotes around each dir
-- run rsync on each line from the text file using shell script loop

it works if I use rysnc at the command line and individually copy the dirctory.

```
rsync -r --include '*.jpg' --include '*.JPG' --exclude '*' --prune-empty-dirs /"media"/"tfrd"/"Disk06_01_M"/"Disk02_01_X"/"x_images and camera"/"vernon pics_other"/"office_PBWT4_YBP6D-7wmff_bpwg4_2vgby"/"office pro disk 2"/"BCM"/"Program Files"/"Microsoft Small Business"/"Business Contact Manager"/"SDKComponents"/"PPCRL"/ /home/tfrd/Desktop/filesync/rsync/dir2/
```

Using Shell Script -- it isn't working - issues are with the dir variable and forward slash or spaces - and most of all -- it seems to try and parse prior to the last directory

I tried variation with the $IFS - because I think this is where the parsing issues is. 

my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
file="/home/tfrd/Desktop/filesync/rsync/test_data_01.txt"

while IFS=$'\n' read -r line
#while IFS= read -r line
#while read line
do

#try 01
#rsync  --include '*.jpg' --include '*.JPG' --exclude '*/*/.' $line /home/rsync/dir2

#try 02
#rsync  --include '*.jpg' --include '*.JPG' --exclude '/*/' $line /home/rsync/dir2

#try 03
#rsync  --include '*.jpg' --include '*.JPG' --exclude '*/*/' $line /home/rsync/dir2

#try 04
rsync --protect-args --include '*.jpg' --include '*.JPG' --exclude '*/*/.' --prune-empty-dirs $line /home/rsync/dir2

done <"$file"
```

My test data: (just 2 lines in a txt file)

```
/"media"/"tfrd"/"Disk06_01_M"/"Disk02_01_X"/"x_images and camera"/"vernon pics_other"/"office_PBWT4_YBP6D-7wmff_bpwg4_2vgby"/"office pro disk 2"/"BCM"/"Program Files"/"Microsoft Small Business"/"Business Contact Manager"/"SDKComponents"/"PPCRL"/
/"media"/"tfrd"/"Disk06_01_M"/"Disk02_01_X"/"x_images and camera"/"vernon pics_other"/"office_PBWT4_YBP6D-7wmff_bpwg4_2vgby"/"office pro disk 2"/"SBA"/"program files"/"Microsoft Small Business"/"Office Accounting 2008"/"SDKComponents"/"PPCRL"/
```

Result: (cleaned up to be readable)

```
tfrd@Beagle-Ubuntu:~/Desktop/filesync/rsync$ clear


tfrd@Beagle-Ubuntu:~/Desktop/filesync/rsync$ ./script.sh 
/media/tfrd/Disk06_01_M/Disk02_01_X/x_images and camera/vernon pics_other/office_PBWT4_YBP6D-7wmff_bpwg4_2vgby/office pro disk 2/BCM/Program Files/Microsoft Small Business/Business Contact Manager/SDKComponents/PPCRL

rsync: link_stat "/media/tfrd/Disk06_01_M/Disk02_01_X/x_images" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: link_stat "/home/tfrd/Desktop/filesync/rsync/and" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: change_dir "/home/tfrd/Desktop/filesync/rsync//camera" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: change_dir "/home/tfrd/Desktop/filesync/rsync//pics_other/office_PBWT4_YBP6D-7wmff_bpwg4_2vgby" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: link_stat "/home/tfrd/Desktop/filesync/rsync/pro" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: link_stat "/home/tfrd/Desktop/filesync/rsync/disk" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: change_dir "/home/tfrd/Desktop/filesync/rsync//2/BCM" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: change_dir "/home/tfrd/Desktop/filesync/rsync//Files" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: link_stat "/home/tfrd/Desktop/filesync/rsync/Small" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: change_dir "/home/tfrd/Desktop/filesync/rsync//Business" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: link_stat "/home/tfrd/Desktop/filesync/rsync/Contact" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: change_dir "/home/tfrd/Desktop/filesync/rsync//Manager/SDKComponents" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1183) [sender=3.1.0]


/media/tfrd/Disk06_01_M/Disk02_01_X/x_images and camera/vernon pics_other/office_PBWT4_YBP6D-7wmff_bpwg4_2vgby/office pro disk 2/SBA/program files/Microsoft Small Business/Office Accounting 2008/SDKComponents/PPCRL

rsync: link_stat "/media/tfrd/Disk06_01_M/Disk02_01_X/x_images" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: link_stat "/home/tfrd/Desktop/filesync/rsync/and" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: change_dir "/home/tfrd/Desktop/filesync/rsync//camera" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: change_dir "/home/tfrd/Desktop/filesync/rsync//pics_other/office_PBWT4_YBP6D-7wmff_bpwg4_2vgby" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: link_stat "/home/tfrd/Desktop/filesync/rsync/pro" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: link_stat "/home/tfrd/Desktop/filesync/rsync/disk" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: change_dir "/home/tfrd/Desktop/filesync/rsync//2/SBA" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: change_dir "/home/tfrd/Desktop/filesync/rsync//files" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: link_stat "/home/tfrd/Desktop/filesync/rsync/Small" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: change_dir "/home/tfrd/Desktop/filesync/rsync//Business" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: link_stat "/home/tfrd/Desktop/filesync/rsync/Accounting" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: change_dir "/home/tfrd/Desktop/filesync/rsync//2008/SDKComponents" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1183) [sender=3.1.0]
```

Comment: Is there some reason to use `rsync` specifically? And not just `cp`?

Comment: Related (duplicate?): [How to copy all HTML files from a directory tree to a single directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12966/how-to-copy-all-html-files-from-a-directory-tree-to-a-single-directory)

Comment: @ilkkachu -- I am using rsync because I have LOTS of duplicated, and I want to do a binary compare plus date compare to make sure I only have one copy and the most recent.

Comment: I have used both solutions - ilkkachu and janos, and both solved the script issues. janos did it first.

I am on to the next problem "why recursive is still happening" -- thanks for the help

Comment: though note that `rsync` mostly saves you just from useless transfers, I don't think it can detect identical files with another name. And by default it only checks the modification time and size; you'll need to use the `--checksum` flag to have it actually check the data. (And within a single host, if you do that, you might as well copy all the data to begin with.) If the timestamp if enough to check, GNU cp has the `--update` flag too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to quote every single path element.

In the text file with the list of paths,
it will be better to not have any quotes,
just the filenames as they are:

```
/media/tfrd/Disk06_01_M/Disk02_01_X/x_images and camera/vernon pics_other/office_PBWT4_YBP6D-7wmff_bpwg4_2vgby/office pro disk 2/BCM/Program Files/Microsoft Small Business/Business Contact Manager/SDKComponents/PPCRL/
/media/tfrd/Disk06_01_M/Disk02_01_X/x_images and camera/vernon pics_other/office_PBWT4_YBP6D-7wmff_bpwg4_2vgby/office pro disk 2/SBA/program files/Microsoft Small Business/Office Accounting 2008/SDKComponents/PPCRL/
```

And then write the script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
file="/home/tfrd/Desktop/filesync/rsync/test_data_01.txt"

while IFS=$'\n' read -r line
do
    rsync --protect-args --include '*.jpg' --include '*.JPG' --exclude '*/*/.' --prune-empty-dirs "$line" /home/rsync/dir2
done < "$file"
```

That's it. Notice that `$line` is enclosed in `"..."` when used as the path argument of `rsync`. This will ensure that any embedded spaces and other special characters are handled correctly.
The entire content inside the `"..."` is treated as a single value,
that's why it works.

Answer (score 0):

You had

```
while IFS=$'\n' read -r line ; do
    rsync ... $line /some/target/dir
done < inputfile
```

With `inputfile` containing lines like this:

```
/"media"/"tfrd"/"blah blah"/"yet another dir"/"foo"
```

You're somewhat on the right track in that using quotes and/or setting `IFS` will help against [word splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting). However, there are some issues.

First, quotes inside a variable don't matter, at all, if the variable is split after expansion, it's split. E.g. `var='"foo bar"'; printf "%s\n" $var` will print `"foo` and `bar"` on two separate lines (they went to `printf` as two arguments). Instead, you need to quote the variable when expanding it, e.g. `var='foo bar'; printf "%s\n" "$var"`.

Second, while the contents of `IFS` control word splitting, you're only setting it to the newline for the duration of the the `read`, not for the rest of the script.  That saves you from `read` doing any splitting, but not from the splitting after the unquoted expansion. Setting `IFS=$'\n';` at the start of the script would have made it effective for the expansion too, but it's still better to quote (because it avoids globbing too).

Since `read` takes newlines as delimiters to stop reading, we might as well give it an empty `IFS`, instead of one with newline.

So, you probably want to have

```
while IFS= read -r line ; do
    rsync ... "$line" /some/target/dir
done < inputfile
```

with the input file containing no quotes

```
/media/tfrd/blah blah/yet another dir/foo
```